# Python Selenium Clicking Buttons

Tags: jquery, python, html, css, selenium

I'm getting an error when asking Selenium to click a tab (or button) in my web app. Please see the code and the CSS selectors below:

Error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: #tab-item-1090 > md-icon:nth-child(1)

CSS Selector for button Patient page button: #tab-item-1090 > md-icon:nth-child(1)

Code for the script. It breaks at the 'patientPage' variable.

```
def createPatient():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(confidential)
    emailElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#input_0')
    emailElem.send_keys('bconfidential')
    passElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#input_1')
    passElem.send_keys('confidential')
    loginElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.md-raised:nth-child(4)').click()
    patientPage = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#tab-item-1090 > md-icon:nth-child(1)').click()
    patientOptions = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.md-fab > button:nth-child(1)').click()
    patientOption_Create = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#menu_container_981 > md-menu-content:nth-child(1) > md-menu-item:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)').click()
    patientCreate_Firstname = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#input_1072')
    patientCreate_Firstname.send_keys('Test')
    patientCreate_Lastname = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#input_1073').click()
    patientCreate_Lastname.send_keys('Script')
    patientCreate_SSN = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#input_1074')
    patientCreate_SSN.send_keys('9812')
    patientCreate_DOB = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.md-datepicker-triangle-button').click()
    patientCreate_DOB_Month = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#md-0-year-2015-8-1 > span:nth-child(1)').click()
    patientCreate_DOB_Day = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#md-0-month-2015-8-16 > span:nth-child(1)').click()
    patientCreate_Submit = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.md-raised:nth-child(2)').click()

createPatient()
```

I'm not sure why this CSS element can't be found, but the Login button's element can be found by CSS selector. I already tried using the Xpath instead. Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Bar

Comment: in the description you are saying `#tab-item-1090 > md-icon:nth-child(1)` but in the code you have `('#tab-item-1090 > div:nth-child(3)')`. Is it possible to add a unique `id` in that button so you don't have to traverse the DOM in Selenium ? Edit: I cannot see the problem cause I don't know the DOM, but probably the selector is not correct ..

Comment: Hey DrNio, I've edited the code. I tried both of these selectors with no luck. What is DOM?

Comment: DOM = "Domain Object Model" it's the structured tree of nodes built from the html webpage that your code is traversing by using those selectors.

Comment: example of simple DOM 

`<html>
 <body>
  <p class="content">Site content goes here.</p>
</body>
<html>` 

This is how you locate the button in Selinium
`content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p.content')`

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is clear `Message: Unable to locate element: #tab-item-1090 > md-icon:nth-child(1)`. So basically when the test is running the selector is not correct and it doesn't find the element in your web app. I would suggest adding a unique `id` for example `<button id='foo'>click me </button>` on that element (button or tab) in your web app and replace the `#tab-item-1090 > md-icon:nth-child(1)` with that `foo`.

Edit: For more help why `#tab-item-1090 > md-icon:nth-child(1)` is not working we need to see the DOM of the web app.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I'm working with my web dev to try to fix this on his end.

Comment: cool! so in the end you will only have to do something like this 
`patientPage = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#patient-page').click()
` much simpler and cleaner and easier to maintain in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

looking at your script, I suggest that you need to include a call to WebDriverWait until method.  The script clicks on a button on a login page, then immediately attempts to click on that patient button.  You should wait for the patient button to be clickable, then search for it to click on it.